# Effienctly unpack mono12packed bitstring format with python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, byte, bit, nibble

I have raw data from a camera, which is in the mono12packed format. This is an interlaced bit format, to store 2 12bit integers in 3 bytes to eliminate overhead. Explicitly the memory layout for each 3 bytes looks like this:

```
Byte 1 = Pixel0 Bits 11-4
Byte 2 = Pixel1 Bits 3-0 + Pixel0 Bits 3-0
Byte 3 = Pixel1 Bits 11-4
```

I have a file, where all the bytes can be read from using binary read, let's assume it is called `binfile`.

To get the pixeldata from the file I do:

```
from bitstring import BitArray as Bit

f = open(binfile, 'rb')
bytestring = f.read()
f.close()
a = []
for i in range(len(bytestring)/3): #reading 2 pixels = 3 bytes at a time
    s = Bit(bytes = bytestring[i*3:i*3+3], length = 24)
    p0 = s[0:8]+s[12:16]
    p1 = s[16:]+s[8:12]
    a.append(p0.unpack('uint:12'))
    a.append(p1.unpack('uint:12'))
```

which works, but is horribly slow and I would like to do that more efficiently, because I have to do that for a huge amount of data.

My idea is, that by reading more than 3 bytes at a time I could spare some time in the conversion step, but I can't figure a way how to do that.

Another idea is, since the bits come in packs of 4, maybe there is a way to work on nibbles rather than on bits.

**Data example:**

The bytes

```
'\x07\x85\x07\x05\x9d\x06'
```

lead to the data

```
[117, 120, 93, 105]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried bitwise operators? Maybe that's a faster way:

```
with open('binfile.txt', 'rb') as binfile:
  bytestring = list(bytearray(binfile.read()))


a = []

for i in range(0, len(bytestring), 3):
  px_bytes = bytestring[i:i+3]
  p0 = (px_bytes[0] << 4) | (px_bytes[1] & 0x0F)
  p1 = (px_bytes[2] << 4) | (px_bytes[1] >> 4 & 0x0F)
  a.append(p0)
  a.append(p1)

print a
```

This also outputs:
`[117, 120, 93, 105]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you explain a little, what is going on in the bitwise operators and why that works?

Comment: Of course I can, but I guess it's more reasonable to look at sources like Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation.

Comment: Well to get you going I'll explain what I did for p0.
I need to construct the 12 bits as follows:
Bits 11..4 comes from Byte1, while bits 3..0 comes from  bits 3..0 of Byte2.
In order to put them together, first I shift Byte1 to the left by 4 bits. So I get Bits 11..4.
To get Bits 3..0 I mask them out from Byte2 with the hex constant `0x0F` (`0b00001111` in binary) and the bitwise `and`. This way I get the second part.
The only thing left is to put them together with the bitwise `or`.

Comment: I'm trying it for p0: By shifting `px_bytes[0]` 4 bits to the left, the 4 rightmost positions become zero. Those are filled with the corresponding first 4 or last for bytes of `px_bytes[1]`. The and operation is a bitmask for only those 4 bits.